# how to extract data from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of value and i want to extract all the subarray inside the array but i don't know how.

Here is the array :

```
[

    [
        "20:00",
        "21:00",
        "22:00"
    ],
    [
        "18:00",
        "19:00",
        "20:00"
    ],
    [
        "12:00",
        "13:00",
    ]
]
```

How  can i make like this : [
            "20:00",
            "21:00",
            "22:00",
            "18:00",
            "19:00",
            "20:00",
            "12:00",
            "13:00",
            "14:00"
    ]

Comment: where does `"14:00"` come from?

Comment: @NickParsons Magic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a multi-dimensional array structure to a flat array with `Array.flat()`:

```js
const arr = [["20:00","21:00","22:00"],["18:00","19:00","20:00"],["12:00","13:00"]]
    
const result = arr.flat()

console.log(result)
```